# Importing SVG as React Component overrides CSS inline style Variables

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, webpack

In my react app, I import an svg as a React Component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {ReactComponent as SomeSVGComponent} from "./some_svg.svg";

function SomeComponent(props){

   return (
       <div>
           <SomeSVGComponent />
       </div>
   );
}
```

The app was created with create-react-app, so webpack manages the import.

The svg's path children have an inline style variable containing the path's length:

```
<svg ...>
...
<path style="--pathLength:180.12531;" d=.../>
</svg>
```

This variable is necessary for my app's animation to work correctly.

However, (I believe this is webpack's doing in this case) when the svg is imported as a react component, the style is overwritten to be `style={{-pathlength:180.12531}}` which causes a compilation error:

```
   Failed to compile.

   SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (8:4)

   6 |   ...props
   7 | }) => <svg width={137} height={46} {...props}>{title ? <title>{title}</title> : null}<path style={{
>  8 |     -pathlength: 762.1506987288266
     |     ^
   9 |   }} .../>
```

Is it possible to maintain the structure of importing the SVG as a ReactComponent without having this inline style variable be overwritten?

Maybe it would be possible to override webpack's import?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error at compilation because `-pathlength:...` is not a valid style attribute in React. Why don't you try assigning the `pathLength` using the `pathLength` inline attribute for `path`.

```
<svg ...>
   ...
   <path pathLength="180.12531;" d=.../>
</svg>
```

Comment: I used to do that but, turns out, safari used to have a bug were they did not take the 'pathLength' argument into consideration. So even in my old ipad (a few years old) svg will just ignore the argument because apple did not fix that for that os.

Comment: Reference from the other comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889547/svg-pathlength-dont-work-on-safari

Comment: @AllanLago Interesting! I didn't know that Safari has a bug with `pathLength`.